# Numpy array stuck in while loop if I enter a number greater than 0.1

Tags: python, numpy, random

What I am trying to do is :

Generating 6 random numbers which multipled for a coefficient and then added among themselves give me a value between ***overall*** - 0.5 and ***overall*** + 0.5. The program works fine with a coefficient in the last position of Gk_coeff (the sixth number of Gk_coeff[5]) which is <= 0.1, but if I enter 0.11, 0.12 (like in the code given) and so on, it stops working. There must be a reason but I really cannot think of it. I've tried using it on linux and windows and the issue persists, so it can't be related to the system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import numpy

overall = 83

Gk_coeff = [ 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.07, 0.12 ]
Gk_values = numpy.empty(6, dtype=int)

calculated_overall = 0

while not (overall - 0.5 <= calculated_overall <= overall + 0.5) :
    calculated_overall = 0
    for i in range (len(Gk_coeff)):
        Gk_values[i] = random.randint(overall - 7, overall + 7)
        calculated_overall += (Gk_values[i] * Gk_coeff[i])

print(calculated_overall)
```

Comment: `overall - 0.5 <= calculated_overall` is evaluated as `overall - (0.5 <= calculated_overall)`

Comment: you also (re)set `calculated_overall` to zero with every iteration

Comment: Your GK_coef don't add up to one.  They add up to 1.1.  So on average, you should expect calculated_overall to hover around 1.1 * overall.  The larger overall is, the harder it's going to be to reach this.

Comment: [Sorry, I made a comment and then realized I misread your code.  You commented on my deleted comment, so maybe delete that too, so the thread works.]

Comment: Sorry if this got buried.  Your Gk_coeff don't add up to 1.  That's the problem.

Comment: @FrankYellin what can I use as a workaround?

Comment: I see someone has answered the question.  You take numbers that average to `overall` and multiply it by 1.1.  You need to normalize.  It's unclear what you're actually trying to do, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop is not exited. The reason is that the random number `calculated_overall` you iteratively generate is, in expectation (and with a very high probability, larger than `overall + 0.5`. In particular, the reason is that

```
ExpectedValue[calculated_overall] = sum(Gk_coeff) * ExpectedValue[andom.randint(overall - 7, overall + 7)]
                                  = 1.11 * 83
                                  = 92.13
```

In turn, the condition for the while-loop always holds as `calculated_overall` practically never falls within the interval `[82.5, 83.5]`.

Normalizing the weights so that they properly sum to `1.0` solves the issue, i.e.

```
Gk_coeff = [val/sum(Gk_coeff) for val in Gk_coeff]
```

provides a random number `calculated_overall` that has expected value of `83` and falls with a high probability within the interval `[82.5, 83.5]` those exiting the while loop.